# Django relationship with User default auth model and another Model

Tags: python, django

I’m developing a web application where users can subscribe to different series of texts, that would be seen inside the system. I want to create a relationship between the `User` and the `SeriesText`, so I can grab the current logged user in the VIEW, and just return all of his subscriptions at the dashboard template.
An user would be able to subscribe to as many series as he wants.

I’m using the default `User` model from `django.contrib.auth.models`, and I’m not sure how to create this relationship.

I read a lot and I think the correct usage here would be `Many-to-many` (is that correct?), so I tried this, using a pivot table/model called `Subscriptions`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as BaseUserClass

class User(BaseUserClass):
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(SeriesText, through="Subscription")


 class SeriesText(models.Model):
    series_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    series_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subbed_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Subscription")


class Subscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    series = models.ForeignKey(SeriesText, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def subscribe(self, user_id, series_id):
        self.user = user_id
        self.series = series_id
        self.save()
```

But that didn’t seem to work, I got errors even trying to use a `User.objects.get(pk=1)`, don’t really know why.

I’m really confused if I need to put the relationship both ways, like created `models.ManyToMany` on `SeriesText` model, and on an extended `User` model (that I don’t even know if that’s really the way to do it). I'm not even sure if that the correct way to make a relationship using the default auth user model.

To be able to later also search for all users subscribed to a series, I think that the `models.ManyToMany` should also be on the `SeriesText` model, is that also correct?

Can someone help me understand if I’m using the correct relationship (many-to-many), and how to make this relationship? Thanks in advance, I’m pretty new to Django I’m hitting a wall here.

Comment: "But that didn’t seem to work, I got errors.." is too thin of a problem description... What happened, what were the errors?

Comment: @thebjorn I've got the classic `matching query does not exist`error. Had really no idea if trying to extend the User model that way I did is even allowed by Django, I think that's the wrong way to do it,  since I saw many others with similar problems and they used the AbstractModel.

Comment: Extending the user model (or abstract user model), usually brings with it more problems than it solves, but there is nothing intrinsically wrong with it. I would either use the solution from my answer, or remove all the m2m fields you have and just handle it yourself through the Subscription model. I think the solution in my answer is your best choice ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add a m2m field on `SeriesText`. Fundamentally, it doesn't matter which model a many-to-many field is attached to (the database will look the same and the data access will be similar if not identical).  Based on my experience, it's better if you don't have to mess with the Django User model:

```
class SeriesText(models.Model):
    series_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    series_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='subscriptions')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.series_name
```

To see how that works, first add some data:

```
s1 = SeriesText.objects.create(series_name='name1', series_text='text1')
s2 = SeriesText.objects.create(series_name='name2', series_text='text2')

u1 = User.objects.create_user('user1')
u2 = User.objects.create_user(username='user2')
u3 = User.objects.create_user(username='user3')
u4 = User.objects.create_user(username='user4')
u5 = User.objects.create_user(username='user5')

s1.subscribers.add(u1, u2, u3)
s2.subscribers.add(u3, u4, u5)
```

Then to fetch all subscribers for a SeriesText (I'm fetching the objects from the database here to show that it is not an artefact of the last two lines above - data has been changed in the database):

```
>>> SeriesText.objects.get(series_name='name1').subscribers.all()
[<User: user1>, <User: user2>, <User: user3>]

>>> SeriesText.objects.get(series_name='name2').subscribers.all()
[<User: user3>, <User: user4>, <User: user5>]
```

to fetch all subscriptions for a user (we declared that the relation from User to SeriesText should be named `subscriptions` in the many-to-many field):

```
>>> User.objects.get(username='user1').subscriptions.all()
[<SeriesText: name1>]
>>> User.objects.get(username='user2').subscriptions.all()
[<SeriesText: name1>]
>>> User.objects.get(username='user3').subscriptions.all()
[<SeriesText: name1>, <SeriesText: name2>]
>>> User.objects.get(username='user4').subscriptions.all()
[<SeriesText: name2>]
>>> User.objects.get(username='user5').subscriptions.all()
[<SeriesText: name2>]
```

If we hadn't declared the related_name we would have had to use the default:

```
User.objects.get(username='user1').seriestext_set.all()
```

which doesn't read as well.

Comment: Thanks mate, that really seems to be exactly what I need. If you don't mind me asking, I then don't really need to create a Subscription model like I did? Because you didn't typed the `through=` parameter. Does `through` creates the pivot table automatically if I had didn't have the model?

Comment: That's correct. If you look in your database, you'll see that django has created a table that looks very similar to your subscription model for the m2m field.  (through tables are usually used when you need data in addition to the two fkeys).