# 'User' object is not iterable error django when using manytomanyfield

Tags: python, django, database

I created a Team model containing a manytomany field for the members. Now while trying to show the names of the teams the user is present in, I am getting a `TypeError at /dashboard/ 'User' object is not iterable` error.
The codes are below:

models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Member')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Team: {self.name} created on {self.created_at}\nMember(s): {self.members.all()}"


class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"User: {self.user} belongs to {self.team}"
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def dashboard(request):
    teams = Member.objects.filter(user__in=request.user)
    context = {}
    context = {"teams": teams
    return render(request, "users/dashboard.html", context)
```

dashboard.html

```
<p>Your teams:</p>
<ul>
    {% for team in teams %}
        <li>{{ team.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Can anyone please help me fix the error and understand what is causing it?

Comment: You don't need the Member model. See my very recent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63290513/django-relationship-with-user-default-auth-model-and-another-model/63291001#63291001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def dashboard(request):
    teams = Member.objects.filter(user__in=[request.user])
    context = {}
    context = {"teams": teams
    return render(request, "users/dashboard.html", context)
```

You want to check if user exists in a list and not user instance itself. Also, I would probably use `id` instead of whole user object.

Comment: thank you very much, i understand the error now, also ill use the id as you suggested